# How to implement app bar action text instead of action icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, appbar

I am trying to implement appbar in the flutter application. I am able to add an action icon that closes the app. I am willing to show the username beside the close action icon. I tried to add new Text() in the action widget array in the appar section. but not able to align it. Is there any way to add action text directly?

[image]

**Code:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //build a form widget using the form key we created above
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(StringRef.appName),
        actions: <Widget>[

          new Container(),

        new Text(
        userName,
        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),

      new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
        tooltip: 'Closes application',
        onPressed: () => exit(0),
      ),
        ],
      ),
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Wrap your Text widget inside Center widget as

```
new Center(
    new Text(
        userName,
        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
   ),
)
```

Comment: Glad it helped ! If the answer solved your problem , please upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: I have the same issue as this question author, and I tried the above answer and not working for me, and u missing a bracket in this code

Comment: You also need to add horizontal padding in order to make the UI look good.
Because by wrapping it with Center, it stays close to the right side of the screen